# Enlarge / Transform UIView Without Effecting UIViewController Clarity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, transform

I would like to Enlarge `UIView` which is a subview of another `UIViewController`.

Currently the `UIView` placed on the right bottom side of `UIViewController`.

What my Enlarge button do is, it will enlarge the `UIView` and `UIView` will fill on above the `UIViewController`. I used `transform` to do this.

Here is my code,

**UIViewController.m (1024*748 size)**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyUIViewController *myUIViewController;  //subclass of UIView

//adding as subview and assigning its "rootView" as self.
self.myUIViewController = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(371, 420, 648, 299)];
self.myUIViewController.rootView = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.myUIViewController];
```

**MyUIViewController**

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *rootView;  

- (void)enlargeView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    @try
    {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
            [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];

            CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale( self.transform, 1.55, 2.4  );
            self.transform = scaleTransform;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            [self setCenter:self.rootView.view.center];
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
    }
}
```

Currently it enlarging well with animation.However there is a clarity issue .

So is there any other way to achieve this Enlarge functionality without effecting `MyUIViewController` clarity ?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try  CGAffineTransformScale( self.transform, 1.0, 1.0 ); i think it should work. while transforming to original. i was making like that before and it all worked for me

Comment: @meth:thats fixed.I just saved the old transform and reset it again :) so there is a little issue with clarity now.. so I have edited the question.

Comment: sorry about the answer i saw this comment after writing answer.

Comment: Setting the `transform` just scales the pixels (resulting in lack of "clarity"), you'd have to set the `frame` of the view.

Comment: @omz: so is there any way to adjust the subviews as per the frame change ? I have added all the subviews programically.thnks

Comment: Set the `autoresizingMask` of the subviews or override `layoutSubviews` in the view that contains them.

Comment: @omz: let me to try.. thanks